# No login after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: upgrade, login, 17.10

I upgraded my Ubuntu's version from 16.0.4 LTS to 17.10. Since then, I'm no longer able to log on the GUI desktop. Only the access to the console is still working. When I entered my password, the desktop could be loaded for around 1 min, then the login screen returned.

Tried to reinstall the Gnome-Desktop or change the ownership of my own home directory.

A backup is available. Nevertheless it would be nice to solve this problem.

Comment: Ubuntu strictly only supports upgrades from LTS version to LTS (ie. 16.04LTS to 18.04LTS [when released]) or via every release which is 16.04LTS -> 16.10 -> 17.04 -> 17.10.  The reason I used 'strictly' is because in theory any upgrade should work (esp. if you don't use GUI), but only those paths are tested.  18.04LTS will be able to cope with 16.04LTS & 17.10s .conf/config files, but not 16.10/17.04.  17.10 can cope with 17.04 config files, but wasn't tested or coded to cope with 16.04 as its not a planned/tested progression.  If you were using GNOME under 16.04: it may be extensions API/ABI

Comment: I ran out of space ... GNOME in 16.04 was 3.18 (API/ABI was 3.18), under 17.10 it is 3.26 which is a large change. Removing extensions would be my first attempt at fixing it (due abi/api breakage due version diffs).  GNOME & its Glib/GTK+ toolkits change heap; XFCE changes little so would be more likely to work...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I solved my problem with the last step mentioned in the article below (before login).

https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-from-ubuntu-16-0417-04-to-ubuntu-17-10